# How to use `typeof` for derived classes to check with `instanceof`

Tags: typescript

This is my use-case:

```js
class Error1 extends Error {
    constructor(somethingDifferent: number) {
        super('anything!');
    }
}

class Error2 extends Error {
    constructor(hellYeah: string[]) {
        super('woho!');
    }
}

type ErrorToHandler = {
    handler: Function;
    errorType: typeof Error; // HOW TO EXTEND this to be able to handle all types of erorrs extending an Error
}

function fnWhichTakesAnyError(err: Error) {
    console.log('DO SOMETHING!');
}

fnWhichTakesAnyError(new Error1(1)); // works without any problem
fnWhichTakesAnyError(new Error2(['2'])); // works without any problem too

const errorHandlers: ErrorToHandler[] = [
    {
        errorType: Error,
        handler: () => { }
    },
    {
        errorType: Error1, // here comes an error, see below
        handler: () => { }
    }
]

function handleError(error: unknown) {
    errorHandlers.find(eh => error instanceof eh.errorType)?.handler();
}
```

The error message:

```
Type 'typeof Error1' is not assignable to type 'ErrorConstructor'.

Type 'typeof Error1' provides no match for the signature '(message?: string | undefined): Error'.(2322)

input.tsx(15, 5): The expected type comes from property 'errorType' which is declared here on type 'ErrorToHandler'
```

if it's not possible to get this working with extended types, is there a way to just put in any type which could be checked by `instanceof`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiBO8D28CM0CmAPALhgdgCYwLLzQDeAsAFDT3TBL4Q7wCuwOKAFBEgFsMOABYBLfAHMAImIBmcjPAI4AXNHzsBAIyUBKSrQbHoEdgAclPAORh8AT1ETJAQmt6A3EYYBfWn5paUEgSRBQAJkxcAmI4MPJqOgYmFjZObngeEQwQEABNDDARdVZ4ZwBtAF0DRJMGM0tM6wB3JBEkN09vegCA2hx7SziyABUkAAk7QhAlaABeQyT6ESmZ+HUAMXZ8LjFmLyXMeJHBjHUByyQ5YZQDvpo5bd3maDl8AHVxYBERsABrDAQACCDlIvCU6xu8Bq3UYzH4MwAdCAkJIbNIAPLQADKGIAsrARuMAJIAOQA4p07rRaG9PmJvr8AcDQfEePgMM0oageKg9J5oAB6QXQVrwP4wZpiURIdg4aB2ezQczIbQzAS0j5fH7-QEg+xgzIcrmG8I8crWcLWaoC4WilAS0XS9pyhUOZWq9XQbhIGk0FKsI5kSZENYQdSGsYh6ZKKrzaDlWG1OpBlAnSwR+IAGlhxhWoaU6h4BjmAD5KNAAsYfDnDsm6hC06dM2RULWU9B8zHIcX5uWKJXYQFKn7HjscHt8J3VhhDTxG5Dtn98EhmvgYYcF9Gw4i5BJCPORH3U+QJKw7MAMFdMCJEQv0xg9AB+RFdtbF6k0IA)

Comment: It doesn't work because `Error1` _can't_ be substituted for `Error`; `new Error1("message")` isn't allowed. You could use e.g. `{ new(...args: any[]): Error }` instead of `typeof Error` to express "anything that can be newed up into an `Error`".

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe! Just found the answer in some NestJs types.. they did the same! Could have gotten this by myself.. stupid me! :D